# InteliJ IDEA artifact not configured properly with Gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, wrapper, artifact

A gradle project configured with **wrapper** version **3.5**. This gradle wrapper version works properly when import as project in **Intelij IDEA 2017.1** and IDEA **war artifact** are available.

I tried to update gradle wrapper version to **4.0.2** and IDEA could not configure artifacts, it shows this Warning:

```
Warning:<i><b>root project 'dummy-trunk': Web Facets/Artifacts will not be configured properly</b>
Details: org.gradle.internal.typeconversion.UnsupportedNotationException: Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: .
The following types/formats are supported:
  - A String or CharSequence path, for example 'src/main/java' or '/usr/include'.
  - A String or CharSequence URI, for example 'file:/usr/include'.
  - A File instance.
  - A Path instance.
  - A URI or URL instance.</i>
```

Maybe someone with the same problem?

I don't know how to get more info about the warning.
I tried to run `> gradlew idea -d` but this debug ouput do not show the warning.

Comment: Did you try 2017.2.1 version? Gradle 4.x should be supported properly there.

Comment: Did you try `gradlew wrapper` to update the wrapper?

Comment: Not tried yet to update IDEA 2017.2. I let you know.

Comment: Yes to wrapper update, changed the wrapper version from 3.5 to 4.0.2 (last version at the moment) and run `gradle wrapper`. In fact I'm sure it's updated because provokes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with IDEA **2017.2.1** + Gradle Wrapper **4.0.2**

Thx to @CrazyCoder for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.

(*) Update to IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5

(*) Use Gralde 4.2.1

(*) Use Gradle local, use `mavenLocal()`

This is a sample (a part of file `build.gradle`)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M5'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}
```